# RuntimeException : The requested database connection named "Default" has not been configured

Tags: phpunit, typo3

I can't find the reason for this exception running unit tests:

```
RuntimeException : The requested database connection named "Default" has not been configured?
```

When I instantiate my class with an setUp() method and write a unit test like this:

```
class myTestClass extends UnitTestCase
{
    protected $subject;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->subject = new myClass();
    }

    /**
    * @test
    */
    public function dummy()
    {
    }
}
```

the error is output. As long as myClass is not instantiated, the tests are working. But this does not make sense. I checked my CLI interpreter configuration in PhpStorm and everything is fine there.

I work with TYPO3 8.7 and additionally use the Nimut\TestingFramework. Does anyone have a solution or suggestion for this? Or maybe the same problem?

Comment: What do you have in myClass?